# How can I arrange JSON data of Array without repetitive statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

First of All, Sorry for my poor English and Thanks for clicking this Question.

I have a raw data like

*appple-red,banana-yellow,kiwi-green,grape-purple,apple-sour,banana-sweet ...*

and I want to make JSON data with this raw data, like

```
[
 {
  apple : {
   color : "red",
   tastes : "sour"
  }
 },
 {
  banana : {
   color : "yellow",
   tastes : "sweet"
  }
 }, ...
]
```

so I trimmed data with *.split("-")* and added JSON element on empty array with repetitive statements(using *for*).

but my result is like

```
[
 {
  apple : {
  color : "red"
  }
 },
 {
  apple : {
   tastes : "sour"
  }
 },
 {
  banana : {
   color : "yellow"
  }
 }, 
 {
  banana : {
   tastes : "sweet"
 }
}, 
...
]
```

There is only few color(*red, yellow, green..*) attributes and tastes (*sour, sweet, spicy ...*)
so maybe I can handle with *if* condition with this.

but my Problem is there is too much repetitive statements for check key of Array element.

I must check existence of 'apple' in all array element and then I can add another attributes.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a map to group the fruits and check if the value corresponds to an specific attribute and set the value in the correct property like this example:

```js
function arrangeFruits(str) {
  const map = {};
  const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple'];
  const tastes = ['sour', 'sweet'];
  const parts = str.split(',');

  parts.forEach((item) => {
    const [index, attr] = item.split('-');
    if (!map[index]) {
      map[index] = {};
    }

    if (colors.includes(attr)) {
      map[index].color = attr;
    } else if (tastes.includes(attr)) {
      map[index].tastes = attr;
    }
  });

  const fruits = [];
  for (const item in map) {
    const fruit = {};
    fruit[item] = map[item];
    fruits.push(fruit);
  }
  return fruits;
}

const result = arrangeFruits(
  'apple-red,banana-yellow,kiwi-green,grape-purple,apple-sour,banana-sweet'
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the the object

```
$currentObject = {
  apple : {
  color : "red"
  }
 };
$newObject  = {
  apple : {
   tastes : "sour"
  }
 };
```

You can try using lodash merge as per documentation here :https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge to deep merge your object into one.

```
_.merge($currentObject, $newObject);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, and I found 'deepmerge' module on Node. It looks like lodash for deep merge. helped a lot!